# (Unity) How do I prevent UI objects from scaling outside the canvas?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I have canvas scaler set to Screen size. In certain resolutions, my objects with non-stretchy anchors (set like that because I want to keep the size ratio) will end up out of the canvas. Is it possible to set them to maybe leave space between other ui objects but not grow out of the canvas bounds, or something similar?

Constant pixel size does change something but it's a different kind of wrong. Stretching the object helps but as I said, I need to keep the size ratio.

Comment: normally you use anchors and say the UI object must be x pixels in from the edge :D

Comment: I have no idea what do you mean both by using anchors "normally" and just saying that it has to be x pixels from the edge, lol.